# Intuition behind Weight of Evidence and Information Value formula

Tags: regression, probability, distance, intuition, information-theory

In credit scoring models, we use Weight of Evidence to create bins for continuous variables and Information value to filter out important variables.
\begin{align}
\text{WoE:} \qquad &\ln \frac{\text{Distr Good}}{\text{Distr Bad}} \cdot 100  \\[10pt]
\text{IV:} \qquad &\sum_{i=1}^n \left( \text{Distr Good}_i - \text{Distr Bad}_i \right) \cdot \ln \frac{\text{Distr Good}_i}{\text{Distr Bad}_i}
\end{align}
Can someone help explain the intuition behind these formulas?

Comment: Instead of adding formulas as images, please try to use LaTeX next time (now I have changed it).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It can be difficult to find sources giving precise definitions and good explanations of these concepts ... there is one R package at CRAN `woe` with a function `woe` one can check, and I found [this paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jmath/2013/848271/) which at least gives precise definitions. So, assume we have a binary response $Y$ and a grouped predictor $x$. As this seems to be used in credit scoring, the binary outcomes are usually called `bad` and `good` which we can encode as 0 and 1. Which is `good` and which `bad` does not matter for the formulas, because they are invariant under switching of the labels. The formulas express a comparison *divergence* of two distributions, the distributions of $x$-labels among the goods, denoted $g_i/g$ and of labels among the bads, $b_i/b$ ($g=\sum_i g_i, b=\sum_i b_i$).

Then we have
$$ \text{woe}_i = \log\left( \frac{g_i/g}{b_i/b} \right)  
$$ where $i$ represents the classes defined by $x$. As $\left( \frac{g_i/g}{b_i/b} \right)$ is a ratio of two probabilities, it is a risk ratio (RR). If $\text{woe}_i$ is large positive, it means that in the group $i$ the `good`s are more frequent than in the full sample (or population, if we have population data), if large negative, `bad`s are overrepresented. If zero the group has the same distribution as the full sample$^\dagger$.

Then for information value:
$$ \text{IV} = \sum_i \left( \frac{g_i}{g}-\frac{b_i}{b} \right)\cdot \text{woe}_i
$$
It is not obvious at a first glance how to interpret this. It turns out that this is a symmetrized Kullback-Leibler divergence, called the J-divergence (or Jaynes-divergence). Let us show this. Now write $p_i, q_i$ for the two distributions. The Kullback-Leibler divergence see [Intuition on the Kullback–Leibler (KL) Divergence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188903/intuition-on-the-kullback-leibler-kl-divergence/189758#189758) is given by
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\KL}{KL}
\KL(p || q)= \sum_i p_i \log\frac{p_i}{q_i}
$$ which is nonnegative, but not symmetric. To symmetrize it, take the sum
\begin{align}
 \KL(p || q)+\KL(q || p) &=\sum_i p_i \log\frac{p_i}{q_i}+\sum_i q_i \log\frac{q_i}{p_i}\\[8pt]
&= \sum_i p_i \log\frac{p_i}{q_i} - \sum_i q_i \log\frac{p_i}{q_i}\\[8pt]
&= \sum_i (p_i-q_i) \log\frac{p_i}{q_i}
\end{align}
(where we used that $\log x^{-1} =-\log x$)
and this can now easily be recognized as the information value $\text{IV}$.

**A warning**: These concepts seem to be much used in the context of univariate screening of variables to use in logistic regression models. That is generally not a good idea, for discussion see [How come variables with low information values may be statistically significant in a logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461740/how-come-variables-with-low-information-values-may-be-statistically-significant/461754#461754).

A prototype implementation in R to experiment with:

```r
library(tidyverse)

myWoE  <- function(data) { # data frame with cols x, y
    woetab <- data %>% group_by(x) %>%
        summarise(total=n(), good=sum(y), bad=sum(1-y) ) %>%
        mutate(gi = good/sum(good),
               bi = bad/sum(bad),
               woe = log(gi/bi),
               iv  = (gi - bi)*woe )
    woetab
    }
```

some test data:

```r
test <- data.frame( x= rep(1:5, each=10), 
                    y= rep(rep(0:1, each=5), 5)) 
                       # some very uninformative data     
test2 <- data.frame( x=rep(1:5, each=20),
                     y=rbinom(5*20, size=1, p=rep(seq(from=1, 
                     to=9, length.out=5)/10, each=20)) ) 
                     # More informative
```

then run and compare the outputs (not included here):

```r
library(woe)
myWoE(test)
woe::woe(test, "x", FALSE, "y", Bad=0, Good=1, C_Bin=5)

myWoE(test2)
woe::woe(test2, "x", FALSE, "y", Bad=0, Good=1, C_Bin=5)
```

$\dagger$: This definition differs from the one used in information theory, used for instance in this [classical book by IJ Good](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0000CHL1R) and discussed by CS Peirce in [this classic 1878 paper](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Popular_Science_Monthly/Volume_12/April_1878/Illustrations_of_the_Logic_of_Science_IV).  There is some discussion of that [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/87182/what-is-the-role-of-the-logarithm-in-shannons-entropy/463828#463828).